# Calculating CPU Utilisation of specific function in Container without using docker api?

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, containers, cpu-usage

I looked at various link on stack over flow and others also & i found one pattern or generic way to calculate the cpu utilisation.
One of the link is below

https://github.com/moncho/dry/blob/07244d36010d1029ee03bda29fa5aec6449ebf61/docker/stats.go#L168

Am trying to calculate the same, on my own. But it seems, whenever i calculate the value its not even close, can anyone verify approach once ? & If not can anyone help me with approach ?

I want to calculate cpu for specific time interval, just to give example.
def something_get_execute()
i want to calculate cpu usage for just this specific function.

For the same am doing following this,
Getting values for user & system from here :

```
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/cpuacct.stat
```

Before function gets execute & after the function gets execute.
After that i get delta for container by using below formula :

```
container_cpu_delta = (cpuacct.stat_final_user - cpuacct.stat_initial_user) / (cpuacct.stat_final_system - cpuacct_stat_initial_system)
```

Meanwhile i do the same, to get the value for host
Before and After the function gets execute i get the value for User and system from :

```
/proc/stat
```

grep the first line and i get 1st & 3rd Param

```
cpu 205434 341 56826 3122952 48119 0 25640 0 0 0
i.e 205434 & 56826
```

And perform the same calculation

```
host_cpu_delta = (proc_stat_final_user - proc_stat_init_user)/(proc_stat_final_system-proc_stat_init_user)
```

& Then finally i do

```
cpu_percentage = (container_cpu_delta/host_cpu_delta) * no_of_cores (am bit confused about this cores allocated to container or cores on the host)
```

However there are some observations:

So many times i have seen the difference of

```
(cpuacct.stat_final_user - cpuacct.stat_initial_user)
```

i.e container is Greater than

```
(proc_stat_final_user - proc_stat_init_user)
```

of Host which i will feel little weird. As Host values contains the cycle of container as well
Am confused about no of cores which to take while calculation, cpus allocated to container or all the cpus on host ?
All things am doing from inside container, like reading all the values.
Please let me know if am missing anything in the calculation, it will be great help.

Thanks a lot :)